# How to tackle this python error - PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Tags: python

I am trying to transfer the content of the file ‘A’ into ‘temp’ file with the help of ‘shutil’ module. But, I am getting below error:

```
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

I also tried to research in google for the same error, however none of them helped me. I am not sure what is going wrong.

I am using windows 10 (64 bit), my python version is 3.7.

The details of the coding are as follows:

```
    import csv
    import shutil
    from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
    import os

    class csvtest():

        def editcsv1(self,filename):  
            filename="data.csv"
            tempfile=NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,dir=r"C:\Users\Sahil\Desktop\python")
            with open(filename,"r") as csvfile2,open(tempfile.name,"w") as temp_file:
            reader=csv.reader(csvfile2)
            writer=csv.writer(temp_file)

            for row in reader:
                writer.writerow(row)
                csvfile2.close()
                temp_file.close()
                os.unlink(temp_file.name)
            shutil.move(temp_file.name,filename)

    abc=csvtest()
    abc.editcsv1(filename)
```

'''

As requested, the traceback message as below :
'''

runfile('C:/Users/Sahil/Desktop/python/stackoverflow5may.py',wdir='C:/Users/Sahil/Desktop/python')

File "", line 1, in 
runfile('C:/Users/Sahil/Desktop/python/stackoverflow5may.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sahil/Desktop/python')

File "C:\Users\Sahil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Sahil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Sahil/Desktop/python/stackoverflow5may.py", line 23, in 
abc.editcsv1(filename)

File "C:/Users/Sahil/Desktop/python/stackoverflow5may.py", line 20, in editcsv1
shutil.move(temp_file.name,filename)

File "C:\Users\Sahil\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 578, in move
os.unlink(src)

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\Sahil\Desktop\python\tmp2gibk4eh'

'''

Comment: Can you add the error traceback message from python? Is shows us the line that fails.

Comment: did you close the file in every program before you are running the script?

Comment: @luigigi - the file is opened twice in this program

Comment: @tdelaney Thankyou for your response. Unfortunately, the trace back message is too long and not allowing me to input here . However, let me know if this helps. Apologies i am unable to format it : 
 ''' File "C:\Users\Sahil\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 578, in move
    os.unlink(src)

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\Sahil\\Desktop\\python\\tmp2gibk4eh' '''

Comment: and please post the full traceback in your question. not in the comments. you can edit your question

Comment: @luigigi Yes, i did ensure that the file was closed before running the script. However, i am not sure about the temp file tho. It doesnt look open from front end, however i probably think it might be open from back end which is causing this error. Thus, with the help of 'temp_file.close()' and 'os.unlink(tempfile.name,filename)' I tried to close the temp file as well. Also, i have added the traceback message editing the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NamedTemporyFile` returns an open file object but you try to open it a second time with `open(tempfile.name,"w") as temp_file`. You had a bug in your for loop (closing the files per row written). So,

```
import csv
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os

class csvtest():

    def editcsv1(self,filename):  
        filename="data.csv"
        with NamedTemporaryFile(dir=r"C:\Users\Sahil\Desktop\python",
                mode="w", delete=False) as tempfile:
            with open(filename,"r") as csvfile2:
                reader=csv.reader(csvfile2)
                writer=csv.writer(tempfile)
                writer.writerows(reader)
        shutil.move(temp_file.name,filename)
        os.remove(f.name)


abc=csvtest()
abc.editcsv1(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you for rectifying my code. I learned something new today thanks to you guys. I have indeed figured out the reason for getting this error and also the solution for it ( thanks to your community). However, now i am encountering new error (a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'). I will try to resolve this on my own and get back to you guys with new query if  help required. You guys doing very good job ! God bless you !

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize the tempfile was binary by default. Also, delete didn't work quite like I though.

Comment: i thought i did replied before....strange the comment somehow got deleted. Perhaps, i wanted to thank you guys for helping me and yes  with the above code i am not getting any error and the results are as expected. You guys rock !!